# Script to intercept google search

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Many times I search for a keyword that I really just want a direct launch to the site.

e.g., I'll type "Stack Overflow" in the google search bar and then click the first link. Instead, I would like to simply go to stackoverflow.com. Obviously there are bookmarks and typing in the addressbar but out of force of habbit and speed I do the google thing. (usually takes about 1-2 seconds rather than finding a bookmark or selecting from the address bar drop down).

Is there a greasemonkey/tampermonkey script that does this or anyone know of a simple way to do this? I want to essentially just map exact search strings(case insensitive) to urls. If I type in something else like "stack overflow greasemonkey" I want the original search.

"stackoverflow" or "stack overflow" => stackoverflow.com, "microsoft" => microsoft.com, or whatever mapping I want(by editing the script to add them).

It should be a relatively easy task. I figure there surely is something out there that does this or that can be modified to do it?

Comment: Have you tried the "I'm feeling lucky" button on the google page?

Comment: @Nelson Too slow. I'm just so used to do searching that it would be much more efficient if I could just force a certain path. Process => "Click Home Button" -> Type text -> "Click first entry". It's done very fast and the first steps are the same for general searching. Would just be easier/efficient if I could do it my way instead of trying to change it to someone elses...

Comment: Essentially I'm so used to searching quickly that I apply it to the some common sites I visit and I would like them to automatically go to my site(essentially using the search box as an address bar for some sites). Trying to change the process now(after years) will just be less productive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cooked some up, this should work both pressing ENTER on search box or clicking the search button:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Google redirects
// @namespace  http://googleredirects.com/
// @version    0.1
// @description  Make redirects based on google searches
// @require    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// @match      http://www.google.com/
// @copyright  2012+, cowboy_kangaroo
// ==/UserScript==


(function () {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var mapping = [ "stackoverflow", "http://stackoverflow.com",
                       "reddit", "http://www.reddit.com",
                       "slashdot", "http://slashdot.org" ];
        $('input[name=q]').keydown(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                v = $(this).val();
               for (i=0;i<mapping.length;i+=2) {
                   if (v == mapping[i]) {
                         window.location.href = mapping[i+1];
                   }
               }
            }
        });
        $("input[name='btnK']").click(function(e) {
            v = $('input[name=q]').val();
            for (i=0;i<mapping.length;i+=2) {
                if (v == mapping[i]) {
                     window.location.href = mapping[i+1];
                }
             }
        });
    });
})();
```

I've only tested it on Chrome with Tampermonkey. Make sure to adjust the @match rule if you are using a google specific country site, like www.google.co.uk or the like.

Comment: Awesome! A little slow in the transition but I imagine it's not the scripts fault... only a few seconds anyways.

Comment: Sometimes the script doesn't get work for some reason. Tampermonkey is grayed out as if the script doesn't match properly. Usually this seems to occur when the url path is like `...google.com/#hl...`. I've added a match on `...google.com/*` but that doesn't seem to help. I'm not sure if it's a problem with the script or tampermonkey...

Comment: Just tried in Chrome 93 nearly 10 years later. Does not work, was not expecting it to work. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an easier way, at least if your browser allows you to edit the search link: Simply replace "&btnG=" or "&btnK=" with "&btnI=".

That should simulate a search with the "I'm feeling lucky" button.